# exporting a module in a callback function?

Tags: node.js, express, module, sequelize.js

is there a way to export some variables that are inside a callback function? for example, if i need to use room.room_id in another file, what should i do? i tried module.exports.roomId = room.room_id but roomId in another file appeared to be undefined.thanks!

```
var Room = require('../models/database').Room

exports.create = function (req, res) {


Room
    .create({
        room_name: req.body.roomName
    })
    .complete(function () {

        Room
            .find({where: {room_name: req.body.roomName}})
            .success(function (room) {

                // if(err) console.log(err);

                res.redirect('rooms/videochat/' + req.body.roomName + '/' + room.room_id);
                console.log("room_id: " + room.room_id);

                module.exports.roomId = room.room_id;
        })

    })
```

};

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like that because modules are evaluated synchronously and you're mutating `module.exports` some time in the future. What you need to do is supply a callback and either pass the value in or use the callback as an indicator that you can successfully read from the exported property.

Comment: thanks for your reply. how do you mean by supplying a callback? where should i place the callback function?

Comment: You could do something like `exports.getRoomId = function(cb) { /* do async calls and call cb(null, room.room_id); or cb(error); on error*/ };` Then in your script that's require()'ing this module, pass in the callback: `require('./foo').getRoomId(function(err, roomId) { ... });`

Comment: i think i understood your explanation. but my existing code is already inside a export. i just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to solve this problem, because modules are read once synchronously and cached but your code seems to handle requests and responses.

You will want rather export something like this:

```
var rooms = {};

exports.create = function (req, res, next) {
  Room.create({
    room_name: req.body.roomName
  }).complete(function () {
    Room.find({where: {room_name: req.body.roomName}})
      .success(function (room) {
        res.redirect('rooms/videochat/' + req.body.roomName + '/' + room.room_id);
        rooms[req.body.roomName] = room.room_id;
      });
  });
};

exports.rooms = rooms;
```

If you are using Express.js, you can register in another place a route like this:

```
var roomsManager = require('./path/to/the/module');

//handle the create room endpoint
app.post('/room', roomsManager.create);

//get the room_id given a room name:
console.log('the room id of "some room" is:', roomsManager.rooms["some room"]);
```

Comment: thanks but i want to export room.room_id so i can use it in other files. how do i do that?

Comment: I think you want to keep a hashmap of room name -> room id. Take a look to my edited answer.

Comment: thanks. my bad i didnt mention room_id is auto_increment in my database. so its redundant to use hashmap like that right?